# Near real time streaming data from 100s customer to Google Pub/Sub to GCS

Tags: google-cloud-storage, streaming, google-cloud-pubsub, near-real-time

I am getting near-real time data from 100s of customers. I need to store this data in Google Cloud Storage buckets created for each customer i.e. /gcs/customer_id/yy/mm/day/hhhh/

My data is in Avro. I guess I can use [Pub/Sub to Avro Files on Cloud Storage template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#cloudpubsubtoavro).
However, I'm not sure if Google Pub/Sub can accept data from multiple customers.
Appreciate any help here, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template is quite simple: it takes all the data of PubSub and store them in an avro file on GCS.

However, it's a good starting point and you can make evolutions on that base to add a split per customer, and the file path that you want.

You can find the [template in Java format on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubsubToAvro.java)